# Push to undefined index in array

Tags: javascript

Is there any better way to push something to undefined index in array instead of this:

```
// Just an example

let array = [];
let indexInArray = 0;
let data = "data";

// This throws error
// array[indexInArray].push(data);

for(let i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    if(array[indexInArray] == undefined) {
        array[indexInArray] = [data];
    } else {
       // This throws error if i = 0
       array[indexInArray].push(data);
    }
}

// array = [["data", "data"]];
```

I am looking for pushing to undefined index in array.

So I need to create array in index and then do push().

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
const array = [];

array[42] ='hello';
```

You can set a value at a specific index in an array simply by assigning to that value.

Comment: I am sorry. I edited my post. I need to push to array in index. I want to do this before always checking if array in index is undefined or not.

Comment: It's can't push anything in that array, In Javascript  array `[]` and objects `{}`  both `typeof` is `objects`, So here you assign a key value pair `array[42] ='hello'` into an array.

Comment: Even you can do this `array[-1] = '-1'`

Comment: @NeelRathod I am looking for something like this. But I need to do this on index in `array` not in `array`.

Comment: @JohnDoe It seems like you want to convert array elements of `undefined` to it's `index`. Ex. `[1,2, undefined]` => `[1,2,2]`

Comment: @NeelRathod Look at my topic. `data` is not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `push` for that, you just need to do this `arr[index] = data`

```js
const array = [1, 2, undefined];
const data = 'Neel';
array[3] = data;
array[10] = data;
console.log(array);
```

> **Note**: If you assign a value on above max index then a value of between index will be `undefined`, Check above snippet for index `10`

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Look at my post. This is not my problem.

Comment: I know that. But I want to push a few data to array[index]. I need array in array[index] and push into it.

Comment: Please put your expect output

Comment: Done. I've already have not idea how to explain it better. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @JohnDoe Happy to help..Anything wrong with this answer? Please comment on, upvote or indeed accept answers. –

Comment: Look at my post. This is not solution. I am looking for push data into array on array[index].